# `ssh <username>@<pika_node_hostname>` instead of `ssh pika_node`

Tags: ssh, server, proxy

```
Host pika
    User <username_1>
    Hostname <pika_hostname>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host pika_node
    User <username_2>
    HostName <pika_node_hostname>
    ProxyJump pika
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

As you can see on the above `.ssh/config`, I use `ProxyJump` in order to connect on a server. This is practice because I can just do `ssh pika_node`. Now, for some reasons, I need to connect on that same server using `ssh <username>@<pika_node_hostname>` without entering a password. For now, if I enter the previous command in the terminal, I just got a `Connection Timed Out` issue. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying different users or same user?
If you are trying diffrent users, plz remember to export id_ed25519 on the target pik_node for that user!